# Every time I clone my object, the clone that was just created gets faster, and a clone of that clone is made. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in my project I have an original object, and every time I hit a specific key it clones the object and adds a movement script to the clone.

The original object moves somewhat slowly, as it has the movement script as well, but then starting from the very first clone, there is a very noticeable increase in speed. It keeps increasing every time I clone, so it must be multiplying against itself every time or something like that.

I'm not sure what to do about this, though I can see that in the hierarchy, when I clone the first time, it makes one clone, which is normal. When I clone a second time, it makes two clones:

GameObject(clone),
Gameobject(clone)(clone)

It seems that it's making a clone of the clone. Though, that clone is unable to move at all, and just sits there. Why are there clones of clones being made, and how can I keep the speed for all the clones at the original speed?

I've tried to look at the code and look at the certain part that deals with instantiating the object, as well as the entire movement script and I'm not exactly sure of what to look for...

This is the movement script(I've included most of the WASD script in order to make this project reproducible):

```
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Rigidbody rb;
    public float thrust = 900f;

    public int Savings;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            //Sets Velocity to zero on Y so it can change direction without delay
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * thrust);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }



        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            //Sets Velocity to zero on Y so it can change direction without delay
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * thrust);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }



        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            //Sets Velocity to zero on Z so it can change direction without delay
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * thrust);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            //Sets Velocity to zero on Z so it can change direction without delay 
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.back * thrust);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Freeze all positions
            rb.constraints = (RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ);
        }





    }
}
```

This is one of the parts of my instantiating script:

```
        if (Savings >= 5 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            CheckIf = CheckIf + 1;
            Debug.Log(Savings);
            //this instantiates or clones ArcadeGame1 and gives it a new position on the area
            GameObject clone = Instantiate(ArcadeGame1, new Vector3(-2, 3, 13), Quaternion.identity);
            //this gives a movement script to the new clone in order to help it move
            clone.AddComponent<MovementScript>();



        }
```

I expect there to be only one clone when I press the cloning key, even after the first time. If I press the cloning key 5 times, there should be 5 clones plus the original.

They should also all move at the same speed as the original. The 5th clone should move just as fast as the original object.

Thank you for helping me with my question.

Comment: *`This is one of the parts of my instantiating script:`* And what is that script attached to?

Comment: This seems to have something to do with static Rigidbody. Try removing static keyword

Comment: Check, where the object is nested. It may be a child of the object you clone from and will move relative from its position. So it will add to the speed.

Comment: @Draco18s the script is attached to the original game object.

Comment: I will try that @mchts                                                                                                   Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ecco .

Comment: Though, still, why when I press the cloning key the second time, why does it make a clone of the second clone? Also, removing static didn't actually stop the speed from increasing in the newer clones, but only made the speed increase by a little bit. If I keep pressing the cloning key there's not as big of a speed difference between the original and the newest clone, but it's definitely slightly faster.

Comment: By the way also: `RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX` X and X and Z? Did you forget Y?

Comment: When you clone the original object, you also clone its Components (also scripts). This is why your clone is cloning as well.

Comment: @Draco18s I think I left that out for some reason, but forgot to add a comment. I'll just add that in to be safe, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @ecco Does this mean that since the clone is a component of the original game object?

Comment: I don't know, where your objects are nested. If the clone is a child of the original, that would explain the speed multiplication. Regarding your spawning script: Like said above; You clone everything. You could disable the script on the cloned object right after you created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a static Rigidbody, all force is therefore being added to same rigidbody everytime you make a new one. The start method is setting the static rigidbody to the most recently created one, so the newest unit is the fastest. Remove the Static keyword from rb, and see if that helps.